# aws amplify sign out button on menuitem

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

i have this structure:

```
  const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

   const handleMobileMenuClose = () => {
setMobileMoreAnchorEl(null);
 };

const handleMenuClose = () => {
 setAnchorEl(null);
 handleMobileMenuClose();
};

const handleMobileMenuOpen = (event) => {
 setMobileMoreAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
};

const handleChange = (event) => {
 setCategory(event.target.value);
}; 
 const menuId = "primary-search-account-menu";
  const renderMenu = (
<Menu
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  anchorOrigin={{
    vertical: "top",
    horizontal: "right",
  }}
  id={menuId}
  keepMounted
  transformOrigin={{
    vertical: "top",
    horizontal: "right",
  }}
  open={isMenuOpen}
  onClose={handleMenuClose}
>
  <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

I would like to add a menu item like this (Sign out) to sign out but it tells me that the function is not defined, I'm missing a silly thing but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong, i use amplify Authenticator.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for your sign out functionality, as shown by [the example](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/#sign-out) provided by AWS Amplify:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

async function signOut() {
    try {
        await Auth.signOut();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing out: ', error);
    }
}
```

Create the `MenuItem` as follows:

```
<MenuItem onClick={signOut}>Sign Out</MenuItem>
```

When this example works for you, then destructure your code to meet your design requirements.